# Downgrade to LTS version, preserving /home partition: Should I expect this to work?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, home-directory, downgrade

Specifically, I'm installing Kubuntu 12.04 over 13.04.  And in fact I've already done it, and it seems to have at least mostly worked, but I'm wondering whether this one anomaly is likely to be attributable to the downgrade; to wit:  I have no window borders|decorations, but only wide, featureless, white---or sometimes black---margins around all my windows.  None of the settings in System Settings (the window border and decorations options are in Workspace Appearance) seem to have any effect.  Is this likely to be fixable, or should I cut my losses and reinstall (formatting the /home partition and restoring any data with `rsync`)?

[image: screenshot showing border anomalies]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue when I downgraded from 13.04 to 12.04 (the unity version) without formatting my /home directory.
 I couldn't change the unity dash settings or even change the wallpaper. It seems that downgrading do not reset those settings.
I solved my problem by deleting all configuration files/folders in my /home folder:

```
cd /home/user_name
sudo rm -rf .*
sudo reboot
```

This will delete any files/folders begining with a '.' and then reboot your pc, correct configuration files will be generated during boot.